# doctrine setParameters from array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere('p.price BETWEEN :min AND :max')->setParameters(array('min' => $price_range, 'max' => $price_max ));
```

I think this is valid query? not working in here. Is there something i miss?

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @Reqven I changed andWhere- > where dont know why its fixed anyway :)

Comment: You have to use "where" before, in order to use the "andWhere", I thought you had other conditions before the code you posted. Just make sure you're using "where" for any first condition with the queryBuilder.

Comment: @Reqven you don't need to use any "where" before see [Doctrine Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#line-number-5775ab09aefa638b14c776a733b4b61d2e324b74-52)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere('p.price BETWEEN :min AND :max')
                                                        ->setParameter('min',$price_range)
                                                        ->setParameter('max', $price_max);
```

Ended Up using 2 setParameter instead Of setParameters

> But somehow in my deep down telling me its wrong but i am new on symfony i guess i run with this anyway